# python networkx, graph with n nodes and each node has k degree

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I tried to write a function that would get 2 arguments: (amount_of_nodes, degree_of_each_edge). This function should build a graph with amount_of_nodes nodes, and each node has degree_of_each_edge degree. This function is not working right, and I need help to fix it, help me please:

```
def k_degree_graph(amount_of_vertex, degree_of_vertex):
    global G
    degree_of_vertex-=1
    G=nx.Graph()
    list_of_nodes = [i for i in range(1, amount_of_vertex + 1)]
    G.add_nodes_from(list_of_nodes)
    for i in range(1, amount_of_vertex + 1):
        for j in range(1, degree_of_vertex + degree_of_vertex%2):
            if i>j:
                buffer=(i, i-j)
            else:
                buffer=(i, i-j+amount_of_vertex)
            G.add_edge(*buffer)
    draw_graph()
```

Comment: Take `amount_of_vertex=10` and `degree_of_vertex=4`.  Then work out by hand what happens in the nested for loop when `i=1`.  What other times does `1` get an edge added to it?  Check `G.neighbors(1)` at the end to be sure.  This should give a good start to what's going on.  There will be cleaner ways to do those nested for loops.

Comment: i cant understand u man, i tried to use neighbours to debug this function, but it gave no effect

Comment: if you call `k_degree_graph(10,4)` and print out `G.neighbors(1)` at the end,what do you get?